# How to separate similar entities mapping based on their key path in RestKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have an object called Filter.
It has two fields - id (string) and title (string). Filter represents filtering of clothes, there are three types of filter - for color, size and brand. I want to have them separated as of now they arrive in same array.

Here is my code:

```
[filtersMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id": @"id_", @"title" : @"title"}];
filtersMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id_"];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:filtersMapping
                                                                             pathPattern:@"catalog/filter"
                                                                                 keyPath:@"size_values"
                                                                             statusCodes:statusCodes]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:filtersMapping
                                                                             pathPattern:@"catalog/filter"
                                                                                 keyPath:@"brand_values"
                                                                             statusCodes:statusCodes]];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:filtersMapping
                                                                             pathPattern:@"catalog/filter"
                                                                                 keyPath:@"color_values"
                                                                             statusCodes:statusCodes]];
```

I get three arrays from server as you can see from mapping. They are size_values, brand_values and color_values. Now when I get mapped result I get one huge array of filter values where all those filters come.

I want to add another property to them that says about their origin, like color or brand, but how do I assign to this property based on the key path I received this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking the `array` from the mapping result, take the `dictionary`. This contains all of the keypaths from your response descriptors as the keys and the array of mapped objects as the values.

You would need to use the keys from the dictionary to update your objects as I don't think the keypath is available in the mapping metadata (though this is worth checking).